# Lucene.vectors: how to set the label field

Tags: lucene, mahout

I am trying to use mahout's lucene.vectors to pull data from a lucene index. The index contains web page content crawled by Nutch. Some of the fields that are indexed are : title, url, id, text and category.

I know I can use lucene.vectors to fetch the data from the index and convert it to vectors. However, what I could not understand is how to tell this tool which field in Lucene contains the label. For my scenario, the category field is the label field.

I am using mahout 0.9.

Thanks in advance,
Ameer

Answer (score 0):

You might need an intermediary step to first convert the lucene index into a sequence file which takes key, values pairs where key represents your label. [`SequenceFilesFromLuceneStorage.java`](http://search-lucene.com/c/Mahout%3aintegration/src/main/java/org/apache/mahout/text/SequenceFilesFromLuceneStorage.java%7C%7Clucene) allows you to do this. The description says the following -

> /**  * Generates a sequence file from a Lucene index with a specified
>   id field as the key and a content field as the value.  * Configure
>   this class with a {@link LuceneStorageConfiguration} bean.  */

I believe the lucene.vector simply places all the text into a vector (Reference - https://mahout.apache.org/users/basics/creating-vectors-from-text.html). You need a sequence file of the format `<Text, VectorWritable>` in order to have a vector along with a label.

Then you can simply read through the sequence file and obtain the vector and label. If you want to calculate TFIDF you can use `seq2sparse` or the `SparseVectorsFromSequenceFiles.java`

Alternatively you can also do this manually by extracting the label first and sending the rest to lucene.vector.

Comment: Thanks. Your comments are really useful. I will use them for future reference. Nevertheless, I have already solved the issue by going a different path. I pulled the data from Lucene, then I formatted that date using mahout's text directory format. I then simply used 'seqdirectory', 'seq2sparse' to get training data. It was easier to do and very direct.